# List all vm of ESXI with python

Tags: python, vmware, vsphere

I tried to list all the `vm`s in my esxi,

```
from pyVim.connect import SmartConnect, Disconnect
import requests
import ssl

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
context = ssl._create_unverified_context()

si = SmartConnect(host="test.dev",
                  port=443,
                  user="username",
                  pwd="password",
                  sslContext=context)

client = si.RetrieveContent()
```

I have this message:

```
 File "test.py", line 2
    import requests
    ^
```

thanks for any response

Comment: Do you have more to your error message?

Comment: i have only this error

Answer (score -1):

My way: python pexpect + "vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms" command

- python pexpect to make a SSH connection to ESXi host
- "vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms" command -> to list all VMs on ESXi host

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).